# Shuffling an array only returns part of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I wrote a function that shuffles the elements of an array.

```
function shuffle(arr) {
  var newarr = [];
  var oldarr = arr;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    newarr.push(arr[index]);
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return newarr;
}
```

For some reason, the function only returns half of the array elements. If an array of 7 elements is passed to it, it returns 4 elements. Similarly, if an array with 8 elements is returned.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `arr.splice(index, 1);` will reduce the array size each time by 1

Comment: You modified the length of the array while iterating through it, that's why.

Comment: You should consider implementing a [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is capable of an efficient, in-place shuffle with an even distribution of possibilities for all permutations, assuming the random number generator is also approximately linearly distributed (which it is).

Comment: the `i` is not used, this is wierd...

Comment: `for(var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {`

Comment: Thank you @AshishRanjan, and sorry for the silly mistake :)

Comment: Thanks @HMR, I think it should be `i > 0` rather that `i >= 0`.

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger in your web browser. Place a break point inside your loop and inspect the state of your variables as your loop iterates, and you'll find your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the length of the array in a variable and use it in a for-loop header instead of `arr.length`. And that `var oldarr = arr` line does nothing in your code.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function shuffle(arr) {
  var newarr = [];
  const length = arr.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    newarr.push(arr[index]);
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }

  return newarr;
}

console.log(shuffle(arr));
```

Note that this is just a quick fix to your problem, not the recommended solution.

And to answer you question - why when you have array of 4 items, the array with only 2 items will be returned - let's look at the execution of that loop where you are decreasing the length of the array in each iteration.

```
iteration;   i;   arr.length;   i < arr.length
   1         0        4             true
   2         1        3             true
   3         2        2             false
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many [Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) which provide a correct and efficient algorithm. In your code, the loop variable increments up to `arr.length`, but in each iteration you diminish that `length` with `splice`, so in total, `i` will only run to about half of the original length, and by consequence your function returns an array of about half the input size.

Quick fix: instead of the `for` loop, use a `while` loop:

```
while (arr.length) {
```

Optional: in order to leave the input array in tact, replace the following useless assignment:

```
var oldarr = arr;
```

...with a copy statement:

```
arr = arr.slice();
```